# Inserting an independent scope variable value in a ng-repeat table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My table is as follows

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="x in referral">
 <td>{{x.id}}</td>
 <td>{{x.name}}</td>
 <td>{{x.region}}</td>
 <td><button data-ng-click="request(x.id)">Request Info</button></td>
 <td><span>{{x.upload_msg}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

and the code is as follows:

```
referral.list($scope.user_id).then(function(response){
   $scope.referral=response.data.data;
   for (i=0;i< ($scope.referral).length; i++){
     $scope.referral[i].upload_msg="";
   }
});
```

The last column is empty initially.
Now when someone clicks on the button, it checks whether a certain condition is met or not and displays a message using the following function in JS

```
$scope.request=function(id){
 data={"user_id":id};
 referral.request(data).then(function(response){
   console.log(response);
   $scope.upload_msg=response.data;
 });
}
```

Functionality is good except for the fact that when i check the status for one row in the table, it displays the value of upload message in all rows. I understand its because i am inserting a scope variable in the table.

I am afraid i don't know how to show the upload_msg value for each row individually.

Help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: One idea would be to add a 'uploaded' attribute to your refferal so that you could add `ng-if="x.uploaded"` to the last td

Comment: or if the upload message is different for each user then add it directly into the user and display it with x.upload_message

Comment: The problem i am facing is how to update the 'uploaded' attribute just for that specific row instead of it affecting all the rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to pass the entire `x` object to your `request` method, and update it accordingly.

```
$scope.request=function(x){
 data={"user_id":x.id};
 referral.request(data).then(function(response){
   console.log(response);
   x.upload_msg=response.data;
 });
}
```

Your `$scope.upload_msg` property was defined for the entire controller, not just one row in your table. So when you have updated the `$scope.upload_msg` property, it was updated for every row in your table. With `x.upload_msg`, you will have a property per row.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

instead of passing just x.id to request method, pass the complete x

```
 <td><button data-ng-click="request(x)">Request Info</button></td>
```

and make request function as follows:

```
$scope.request=function(ref){
 data={"user_id":ref.id};
 referral.request(data).then(function(response){
   console.log(response);
   ref.upload_msg=response.data;
 });
}
```

Comment: Works too. Thanks for the help.